# Is there any risk if I call clear when loop a vector?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to call `clear` when loop to visit the `vector`. I think this will be dangerous, but in my experiment code below, it seems ok to run, it just stop the loop when i called `clear`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    a.clear();  // just run once, then loop exited
    cout << "i = " << i << endl;
  }
}
```

Is there anything I don't know about the risk? could you help on this?

Comment: No. Just make sure if any elements inside the vector are allocated memory that they are dealloacted first.

Comment: Your code will do fine, but it will do a lot of unnecessary cleaning. Also I see some bad coding habits already (are you learning C++ through a competitive coding site?). Anyway don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>` use `#include <vector>`. Don't use `using namespace std;`. Use `\n` instead of `std::endl`.  Give your variables readable names (not just a ). And for loops on containers consider using range based for loops : `for(const int value : values)'

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- This non-standard file includes every header, slowing down compilation.  You also do not learn what headers to include for a standard C++ application by using this.  You could have simply had `#include <vector>` and `#include <iostream>` -- just two headers instead of 20+ headers being included by using that `bits` header.

Comment: @PepijnKramer   It won't do a lot of "unnecessary cleaning".   The first iteration of the loop clears `a`, so `a.size()` is then zero.   The loop body is therefore only executed once.

Comment: @Peter Right ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer With a ranged-for loop the `clear` would invalidate the iterator used under the hood.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Good point too, thanks! (Guess I missed that because I wouldn't even consiously think of writing a loop like that).

Comment: @PepijnKramer I'm not sure I've ever used `clear` before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very, very major temptation that when you have a loop that looks like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
```

then you will be under the impression that looking at `a[i]` and/or modifying it, freely, inside the loop, whenever you have an urge to do so, is perfectly acceptable.

And it is. Unless you already did a

```
a.clear();
```

Alone, by itself, there's nothing wrong with just the code you showed. It's defined behavior. But as soon as `a` is `clear()`ed, doing something with `a[i]` becomes a no-no, inside the loop. But resistance is futile. At some point it's a near certainty that you'll forget that you `clear()`ed the vector, decide to take a peek at `a[i]`, and have to deal with [demons flying out of your nose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon).

If your goal is to stop the loop, a simple `break` will do. If there is a separate reason to `clear()` the vector, do so, but immediately `break` from the loop as well, to avoid giving in to the temptations of creating nasal demons.